# "Unwrapping" SklearnClassifier Object - NLTK Python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nltk

I have used the SklearnClassifier() wrapper from the NLTK python package to train a couple of sklearn classifiers (LogisticRegression() and RandomForest()) for a binary classification problem where text are features. Is there any functionality that allows one to "unwrap" this object so that one can access things such as parameter estimates (for logistic regression) or the variable importance list from the random forest (or any of the items available from the original sklearn object)? The nltk classifier object can score new instances so the underlying information must be contained in that object somewhere? Thank you for you thoughts.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You might want to check out [how to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  Formatting your question correctly will go a long way to getting you the answer you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your classifier is hidden under _clf variable.

```
classifier = SKLearnClassifier(MLPClassifier())
mlp = classifier._clf
```

Documentation found at http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/classify/scikitlearn.html :

```
def __init__(self, estimator, dtype=float, sparse=True):
    """
    :param estimator: scikit-learn classifier object.

    :param dtype: data type used when building feature array.
        scikit-learn estimators work exclusively on numeric data. The
        default value should be fine for almost all situations.

    :param sparse: Whether to use sparse matrices internally.
        The estimator must support these; not all scikit-learn classifiers
        do (see their respective documentation and look for "sparse
        matrix"). The default value is True, since most NLP problems
        involve sparse feature sets. Setting this to False may take a
        great amount of memory.
    :type sparse: boolean.
    """
    self._clf = estimator
    self._encoder = LabelEncoder()
    self._vectorizer = DictVectorizer(dtype=dtype, sparse=sparse)
```

Comment: It's been a while. I'm not sure if this is a new feature or I missed it. Thanks!